# put is not a member of StorageReference at it's value of type

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

It's giving me this error: Value of type 'StorageReference' has no member 'put'

Heres the Code:

```
if let imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.2) {

        let imgUid = NSUUID().uuidString

        let metadata = StorageMetadata()

        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).put(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil {

                print("did not upload img")
            } else {

                print("uploaded")

                let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString

                if let url = downloadURL {

                    self.setUser(img: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error occur in this line:

```
Storage.storage().reference().child(imgUid).put(imgData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
```

I searched for like every other post according to this error but nothing helped me... I didn't touched this project in a while,I just know, that it's might be because of the new Firebase 5

Answer (score 0):

From a quick look at the documentation it looks like the method is now `putData`. See the [guide to uploading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory) and [reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasestorage/api/reference/Classes/StorageReference#putdata_metadata). From the guide:

> ```
> let uploadTask = riversRef.putData(data, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
>   ...
> ```